# Как при маленький ширине выронять два блока один над другим

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть два блока.Каждой определил по *6 блоков Bootstrap*-овских.Если посмотрите при большой ширине экрана то увидите что при больших экранах они выравниваются одним блоком горизонтально.

> **Вопрос:** Как правильно выровнить их(при маленьких экранах) блоком 3 на 3 один блок над другим.

И при каждом блоке должен быть по двум border-ом между элементами.

```css
.navbarfooter-links {
    display: flex;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.navbarfooter-linksleft, .navbarfooter-linksright {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbarfooter-linksleft {
    text-align: right;
}
.navbarfooter-linksright {
    text-align: left;
}
.navbarfooter-linksright:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color : hsla(0, 0%, 4%, .3);
    margin: 0 15px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.navbarfooter-mainlink:nth-child(n+2):before {
     content: ""; 
     display: inline-block; 
     height: 10px; 
     width: 1px; 
     background-color: hsla(0,0%,4%,.3); 
     margin: 0 15px; 
     pointer-events: none;  
}
.navbarfooter-mainlink {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.navbarfooter-mainlink {
    font-size: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbarfooter-links container">
    <div class="navbarfooter-linksleft col  col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 no-padding">
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CAREERS</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">ABOUT</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">SUPPORT</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-linksright col col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 no-padding">
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CONTACT US</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">PRESS</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">API</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените у элементов с классом "**navbarfooter-**" класс **col** на **col-12**

Comment: нее не то ваш вариант не помогло к сожалению :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="navbarfooter-links container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navbarfooter-linksleft col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 no-padding">
      <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CAREERS</a></div>
      <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">ABOUT</a></div>
      <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">SUPPORT</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-linksright col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 no-padding">
      <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CONTACT US</a></div>
      <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">PRESS</a></div>
      <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">API</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Попробуйте сделать так, должно сработать

Comment: нет не получилось